# Checksum Calculation - two's complement of the least significant byte

Tags: java, android, network-programming

I'm attempting to create a check sum by calculating the two's complement of the least significant byte of the sum of all the data bytes in an array.

So given an array:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x02 };
```

would something like this work...

```
 public static void main(String []args)
 {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x02 };

    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(bytes);

    BigInteger biRes = bi.not().add(BigInteger.ONE);

    byte[] result = biRes.toByteArray();

    System.out.println("a: " + result);

    System.out.println("b: " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(result));
 }
```

Produces...

a: [B@34bdb859
b: FEFE

Is this correct?

Comment: @w0051977 What part of 'least significant' don't you understand?

Comment: @EJP, I have deleted my comment as it was not right.  Thanks.  +1 for the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution :

```
private static byte calculateChecksum8(byte[] bytes){

    byte result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++){
        result += bytes[i];
    }       
    result = (byte) (~ result & 0xFF);
    result = (byte) (result +1 & 0xFF);

    String str = String.format("%02x", result);
    System.out.println(result+" = "+str.toUpperCase());

    return result;
}
```

Someone to confirm ?

Comment: I confirmed with +1

Comment: This is 8 bit checksum aka two's complement

Answer (score 0):

Just add up all the bytes, negate the resuit, cast or truncate it to a byte, and you're done.

Comment: why would you add up the bytes? I think your step two and step three are good, but I don't understand step one.